# NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript

It shows these lines as the source of the problem, how can I solve this chronic problem?

[product-html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoT1g.png)

[product-ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VK2z.png)

[error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkweN.png)

**Product.html**

```
<div *ngIf="showProductsDetail" #productDetailsElement>
    <mat-card appMaterialElevation class="product-details">
        <mat-card-header class="mt-3">
            <mat-card-title>
                <mat-icon><img class="details-icon" src="assets/icons/information.png" /></mat-icon
                >{{ "PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_DETAILS" | translate }}
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
```

**Product.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const filterValue = "";

    this._store$.dispatch(new OnlineProductsStoreActions.GetOnlineProducts(this.filter));
    this._store$.dispatch(new OnlineProductsStoreActions.SearchProduct(filterValue, this.filter));
    this._store$.dispatch(new OnlineProductsStoreActions.HomePageCategory());

    this.onlineproductsEffects.getOnlineProductsHomePageCategory$
        .pipe(
            filter((action) => action.type === OnlineProductsStoreActions.ActionTypes.HOME_PAGE_CATEGORY_SUCCESS),
            takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
        )
        .subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.SelectHomePageCategories = res;
        });
```

I can't find what changed...

Comment: If you cant debug, than comment the codes that might be suspected till you find where error is coming.

Comment: [why should you not upload image of code or Error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you @StefaniTotokotsopoulou but it would be a bit difficult to try it as it is a big project

Answer (score 0):

> Ensure that there are no changes to the bindings in the template after change detection is run. This often means refactoring to use the correct component lifecycle hook for your use case. If the issue exists within **ngAfterViewInit**, the recommended solution is to use a constructor or ngOnInit to set initial values, or use ngAfterContentInit for other value bindings.

check if you can move some of that code to the ngOnInit method